# I can't figure out why my Label isn't triggering the converter when inside of span, but does when it isn't? What am I missing here?

Tags: xaml, maui

I have two Label examples for the same data.  One works - but doesn't work like I want it to (it colorized all of the text based on the community name rather than both the community name and the username being different colors), the other works - but doesn't trigger the converter to fire (so the text displays as expected, but doesn't run through the converter for colorization). I *think* the second one that doesn't trigger the convertor is what I'm after.

#### Working Label, but doesn't do what I want

```xml
<Label 
    x:Name="communityAndUserLabel"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="1"
    FontAttributes="None"
    VerticalOptions="End">
    <Label.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} • {1}" Mode="TwoWay">
            <Binding Path="CommunityName" />
            <Binding Path="Username" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Text>
    <Label.TextColor>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource nameColorMulti}" ConverterParameter="community">
            <Binding Path="CommunityName" />
            <Binding Path="Username" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.TextColor>
</Label>
```

#### Label that won't trigger the converter, but still shows the text

```xml
<Label 
    x:Name="communityAndUserLabel"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="1"
    FontAttributes="None"
    VerticalOptions="End">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="{Binding CommunityName, Mode=TwoWay}" TextColor="{Binding CommunityName, Converter={StaticResource nameColorMulti}, ConverterParameter=community}" />
            <Span Text=" • " TextColor="Gray" />
            <Span Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay}" TextColor="{Binding Username, Converter={StaticResource nameColorMulti}, ConverterParameter=username}" />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

Any idea on what I'm overlooking here on why the second one doesn't trigger the converter?

- [View](https://github.com/ReticentRobot/Disc/blob/master/Views/HomePage.xaml)
- [ViewModel](https://github.com/ReticentRobot/Disc/blob/master/ViewModels/PostsViewModel.cs)
- [Converter](https://github.com/ReticentRobot/Disc/blob/master/Converters/NameColorMultiConverter.cs)
- [App.xaml](https://github.com/ReticentRobot/Disc/blob/master/App.xaml)

Comment: you haven't explained what you're actually trying to accomplish

Comment: I'm trying to get a converter named NameColorMultiConverter (with x:Key="nameColorMulti" assigned in App.xml) to trigger with the bottom label.  That converter changes the Username and CommunityName TextColor based on their value.  The top label example triggers it, but colors the entire string based on the CommunityName Value.  The converter should work to color both separately, so I needed to separate CommunityName and UserName (hence changing it to spans), but the bottom Label doesn't trigger the converter for whatever reason.

Comment: I added some more details in the question too.  Let me know if that's not what you mean and I'll try again to explain.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, we couldn't find the code of  `Converter`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!  Link should work now, I had grabbed the old file name before.

Answer (score 1):

It dawned on me this morning that since I had separated the text out in the xaml I no longer needed to use a IMultiValueConverter - so instead I created two separate IValueConverters to get this done:

```xml
<Label 
    x:Name="communityAndUserLabel"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="1"
    FontAttributes="None"
    VerticalOptions="End">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <!-- Use Binding markup extensions with Converter attributes -->
            <Span Text="{Binding CommunityName}" TextColor="{Binding CommunityName, Converter={StaticResource communityNameColor}}" />
            <Span Text=" • " TextColor="Grey" />
            <Span Text="{Binding Username}" TextColor="{Binding Username, Converter={StaticResource usernameColor}}" />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```